# functions in PYTHON

Tags: python, function

```
def other_new_function():
    print "HELLO"

print "Start", other_new_function(), "Stop"
```

The output of this program is:

```
Start HELLO

None Stop
```

Why is `NONE` being showed in the output?

Comment: `return "HELLO"` instead of `print "HELLO"`

Answer (score 4):

Because you're *printing* `"HELLO"`, and not *returning* it.

Because your function does not return anything, it defaults to returning `None`. Hence, the `None` that appears.

Change:

```
def other_new_function():
    print "HELLO"
```

To:

```
def other_new_function():
    return "HELLO"
```

---

There's a big difference to returning and printing something from a function:

```
>>> def func():
...     print 1
... 
>>> def func2():
...     return 1
... 
>>> myvar = func()
1 # Printed
>>> myvar2 = func2() # Returned to a variable
>>> print myvar
None
>>> print myvar2
1
```

Because function 1 prints the value, it never gets returned to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def other_new_function():
    print "HELLO"
```

returns `NoneType` (which gets printed as 'None') since you dont explicitly return a value. What you probably want to do is:

```
def other_new_function():
    return "HELLO"
```